# OpsHub Migration of items with attachment fails (Bad Gateway)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I try to migrate my Work-Items from TFS 2012 to VSO using the OpsHub migration tool. I get the following error for multiple items (all items with attachment):

> OH-TFS-Connector-0017: Could not load attachment with URL http://server:8081/tfs/*/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/AttachFileHandler.ashx?FileID=1359&FileName=Attachment.zip. Server Error : OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getAttachmentInputStream. Server Error : The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.

how can I fix this?
And is it possible to "migrate" some items manually and tell the program that I migrated it?

Comment: As we know that 502 Bad Gateway error message means one server received an invalid response from another server. So several things you can have a try: 1). Open the http://server:8081/tfs/*/WorkItemTracking/v1.0/AttachFileHandler.ashx?FileID=1359&FileName=Attachment.zip URL directly in IE browser to see whether it is valid; 2). Start a new browser session; 3). Clean browser cache/cookies; 4). Start browser in safe mode. Check this link for the detailed information: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm

Comment: Hi, I Agree. Mostly likely the same attachment is not accessible through URL. I am afraid, however there in case of such failure, the migration cannot proceed further.

Comment: Actually the URL was valid, I don't know why i got the error, as a workaround I just downloaded the attachments deleted them migrated the affected items and added them again to the VSO items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I downloaded the attachments manually and then deleted them from the work items. The migration will then be able to continue. Afterwards manually update the attachments to the affected work items.